# I installed tensor flow from in command prompt and I cant access in anaconda

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda

I have downloaded the tensor flow using `pip install tensorflow` but when I try to access in the anaconda promy it show no module name tensor flow.

Is asking again to download the TensorFlow.
Kindly help me!

Answer (score 0):

You should not mix conda and pip installations.

First, check if the `pip` installation you did was successful: run `pip freeze` and look at the output. If `tensorflow` is in the list, it was successful.

Then, if it's installed, uninstall it via pip: `pip uninstall tensorflow`.

Finally, you can install tensorflow through conda by running `conda install tensorflow`.